# ERROR 1491 (HY000) : The PARTITION function returns the wrong type

Tags: mysql, partitioning

mytable like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `test1` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `md5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`project_id`,`md5`),
  KEY `index_id` (`md5`),
 ) ;
```

I want to partition by md5. so I create a function:

```
   alter table test1 partition by HASH(FLOOR(`md5`)) PARTITIONS 5;
```

but it failed:

```
    ERROR 1491 (HY000) The PARTITION function returns the wrong type
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`FLOOR` is expecting a numeric argument.  If the MD5 string is `c51ce410c124a10e0db5e4b97fc2af39`, then that is treated a 0.  Nearly half of md5s will be treated as zero.

HASH partitioning is virtually useless.  IT certainly won't provide any performance.